# Defining factory in AngularJS and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have a angular module which is handling a service as below

```
(function(){
define('rightClickEventHandler',['angular'],function(){
    angular.module('rightClickEventHandler',[])

    .factory('rightClickEventHandler',function(){
        var events ={};

        events.addMenu = function(){
            console.log('this is a add menu');
        };

        events.deleteMenu = function(){
            console.log('this is a delete menu');
        }

        return events;
    });
});
})();
```

Using 'define' since I'm using requireJs also, all works good till my factory name is 'rightClickEventHandler' same as the module name, but when i change the name to something else i get error as below

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: rightClickEventHandlerProvider <- rightClickEventHandler <- topMenuRightClickCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/unpr?p0=rightClickEventHandlerProvider[object Object]3C-%rightClickEventHandler%%3C-%topMenuRightClickCtrl
```

Can someone please suggest what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer , must read the documentation more carefully.

The problem was during the injection of the service in the other module

Previous:

```
.controller('topMenuRightClickCtrl',['$scope','$http','commonData','rightClickEventHandler',
    //function to read the json from local computer 
    //this is to be replaced by the webservice call
    function($scope,$http,commonData,rightClickEventHandler){
```

I was injecting the module name instead of the service name

Rectified code:

```
.controller('topMenuRightClickCtrl',['$scope','$http','commonData','ServiceName',
    //function to read the json from local computer 
    //this is to be replaced by the webservice call
    function($scope,$http,commonData,ServiceName){
```